# How to adjust JS code to replace link text once a timer expires

Tags: javascript, timer

Basically I have a timer on a page that, when expired, will change the links of a specific class.

Here's the code:

```
var expiry = function() {
            $("#promo-block").remove();
            $("#full-price").show();
            $(".purchase-link").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("href","http://example.com");
            });
        };
```

What I'm also hoping to do is change the link text of the link when the timer expires as well (from "Save $XX Now" to "Click Here to Purchase").

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's the issue? Change the text.

Comment: Go read the [API](http://api.jquery.com/). It's very well documented: [`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

Get the class/id of "Save $XX Now" and use jQuery to modify the HTML.

ie.

HTML:

```
    <span id="purchase">Save $XX Now</span>
```

JS:

```
    $('#purchase').html('Click Here to Purchase');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple jQuery question. Use the `.text()` method.

```
$(".purchase-link").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("href","http://example.com").text("Click Here to Purchase");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/text/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the link is plain text you could use the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method and do something like this:

```
function expiry() {
  $("#promo-block").remove();
  $("#full-price").show();
  $(".purchase-link").each(function() {
    var link = $(this);
    link.attr("href", "http://example.com");
    link.text("Click Here to Purchase");
  });
};
```

And then just use a [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(expiry, 3000); // 3 seconds
```